# Cherrypy ::: fail to load index.html

Tags: jquery, python, cherrypy

I have this folder structure:

```
             index.html 
 tutorial -> public -> css -> style.css
             tut.py
```

where `tutorial`is root.

inside `tut.py`, which I run as `python tut.py`,
this snippet sets root (tutorial):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     conf = {
         '/': {
             'tools.sessions.on': True,
             'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

and this maps `static` content to public:

```
         '/static': {
             'tools.staticdir.on': True,
             'tools.staticdir.dir': './public'
         }
```

also the code serves `index.html` through this:

```
class StringGenerator(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return open('index.html')
```

inside index.html:

```
   <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but when I run `127.0.0.1`, `html` is not being served. What is wrong?

Comment: Everything looks fine. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified how (or if) you're mounting your StringGenerator() class. e.g.

`cherrypy.quickstart(StringGenerator(), "/", conf)`

...or...

`cherrypy.tree.mount(StringGenerator(), '/', conf)`

Unless I misunderstood and your problem is that index() is being invoked but the file fails to load, in which you can try using the full path to see if it solves your problem...